# Регулярное выражение для поиска названия функции

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть, например, такая строка `Ты{@rand(, я думаю random,| скорее всего|, должно быть,)} человек`
Мне нужно:

- найти название функции - **rand**
- забрать в массив параметры, то есть `explode('|', ', я думаю random,| скорее всего|, должно быть,')`

С пробовал написать такой код

```js
<?php

$message = "Ты{@rand(, я думаю random,| скорее всего|, должно быть,)} человек";

preg_match_all('/\s*\{@rand\(.+\)\}/ui', $message, $variants);

foreach($variants[0] as $funcCall) {
  $funcName = trim(preg_replace('/[^@a-z]/ui', '', $funcCall), '@()');

  echo $funcName;

  $arguments = explode('|', trim(preg_replace("/[\{\}@\(\)$funcName]/ui", '', $funcCall)));
  print_r($arguments);
}
```

Это работает, но если в параметрах нет английских символов.
Насколько я понял, чтобы ограничить до этой скобки перед параметрами, нужно использовать `?=\(`
Я пробовал `/[^@a-z?=\(]/ui`, но это не работает так, как я задумал -_-

Как ограничить область до знака ( ?

Comment: Бред это или нет, но меня интересует решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

несколько, забегая вперед, вы в результате то что-то такое хотите получить?

```
$str = "Ты{@rand(, я думаю random,| скорее всего|, должно быть,)} человек.";;

$result = preg_replace_callback('/{@rand\((?<params>.+?)\)}/i', function($m){
                $params = explode('|', $m['params']);
                
                return $params[rand(0, count($params) - 1)];
                
            }, $str);
            
echo $result;
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, только нужно, чтобы можно было получить название функции. Но с этим я сам справился по аналогии)

Comment: @Colorkat вы там на всякий случай ограничьте перечень функций, а то так и `{@unlink("./index.php")}` можно написать какой-нибудь

Comment: Спасибо) Но строка с функциями берется из JSON словаря на сервере. А функции в отдельном классе лежат, так что ничего плохого не должно случится) А так это бот, кстати

Comment: Появилась нужда обрабатывать строки такого типа `ты {@ranf(123| {@rand(...)} )}` То есть внутри функции тоже функция используется. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: @Colorkat с этим лучше новый вопрос задать, более детально описав проблему.